# Parent-child; sit next to each other on an all-inclusive flight?

Tags: air-travel, vacations, children

I have booked an all-inclusive vacation which includes flights to and from the destination (Condor, direct one-leg flights). From the travel company, I got a booklet with vouchers for all the things included - i.e., as far as I understood the instructions, I'll go to the Condor booth at the source airport, show them the voucher, get the tickets (at which time the check-in is performed by them), check in my luggage, go through security, board the plane, and that's it.

I am traveling with my 9 year old child. Is it guaranteed (or at least very highly likely) that we will sit next to each other on the flight? Or should I do something to make this more likely/guaranteed, up front? *Can* I usually influence that?

The flight is at noon, and I could trivially go to the airport on the previous afternoon to get my tickets then, assuming that there will be more than enough not-yet-checked-in seats available at that time. But would this be advisable for this kind of travel, or would this just complicate the standard tourist vacation process, and introduce the possibility for errors?

I have no experience with this type of vacation/travel; I am flying a lot, but only alone and usually in a business context, i.e. always with electronic check-in through my frequent flyer card, and only alone, so I have full control / knowledge over everything up front. I have no status with Condor, never flown with them, and never had a ticket made for me in this way through an agent.

Comment: Talk to your travel agent and/or Condor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Condor lets you [select](https://www.condor.com/eu/fly-enjoy/on-board/seats.jsp) your seats (for a small fee) days in advance. This also works for Economy, or travels booked through a travel agency, like in this case.

You can check-in the evening before at the airport; costs are about 1/3 of the online selection.

You can do the online check in 24h before (though, in Economoy, that will pick the seats for you, seemingly, i.e. it's not guaranteed where you sit).

If you cannot or do not want to do that, arrive at the airport as early as possible (3 hours or more) and be the first to check-in and tell the attendant that you want to be seated with your children.

If all the seats have already been assigned and you are not seated next to your children, you can do this on the plane, either ask the person seated next to you (or next to your kid) to switch seats.

Always ask and tell the flight attendant.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion that there is no "standard" regulated parent-child-sit-together-feature. I talked with the airline, and it was pretty unhelpful. I was aware of the seat-selection upgrade tnks to you, and if I had not brought that up myself, they would have stopped at "be there in time and hope for the best". I have a pretty tight window on both flights, so cannot be there very early. They were not able to tell me if I can use the select-feature with my booked class. I'll try that later, and I'll hope for the best... (and do some human engineering on board, if all else fails)

Comment: I have meanwhile talked to the travel agent and got even more options from them - I have taken the freedom to add those to your answer, pending peer review.